# In this Outlook 2007 application, how come the Explorers.NewExplorer event is not firing?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Here's some sample code:

```
    private Outlook.Application applicationObject;
    public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("on connection");
        applicationObject = (Outlook.Application)application;
        applicationObject.Explorers.NewExplorer += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler(Explorers_NewExplorer);
    }

    void Explorers_NewExplorer(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer Explorer)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("new explorer");
    }
```

the "new explorer" message never appears on the screen because the NewExplorer event never fires, not even when I click on "Open in New Window".

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Explorers` instance on which you're subscribing to the `NewExplorer` event is probably getting garbage-collected. To prevent this from happening, preserve a reference to it through an instance variable:

```
private Outlook.Application applicationObject;
private Outlook.Explorers explorers;

public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
{
    MessageBox.Show("on connection");
    applicationObject = (Outlook.Application)application;
    explorers = applicationObject.Explorers;
    explorers.NewExplorer += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler(Explorers_NewExplorer);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem :-) Take it as a general rule: Whenever you subscribe to a COM object's events, you need to keep that object alive.